# Is there a way to make a response from Python requests a list within a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the Python requests library to get some data from an API. However, within the output dictionary, I would like to have a list. I want to have a list within the `data_providers` key where the first entry for `name`, `url` and `api_url` to be hard coded and the second entry to be gotten from the response.
Currently I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`, and my code look like this

```
output_dict = {
    'data_providers' : {
        {
                    'name': 'NBN Atlas',
                    'url': 'https://registry.nbnatlas.org/datasets',
                    'api_url': 'https://registry.nbnatlas.org/ws/dataResource',
        },
        {
                    'name': owner_name,
                    'url': owner_url,
                    'api_url': owner_api_url,
        },
    }

}
```

After running the code and dumping it into a JSON file my desired response should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "data_providers": [
      {
        "name": "NBN Atlas",
        "url": "https://registry.nbnatlas.org/datasets",
        "api_url": "https://registry.nbnatlas.org/ws/dataResource"
      },
      {
        "name": "Marine Biological Association",
        "url": "https://registry.nbnatlas.org/public/show/dp80",
        "api_url": "https://registry.nbnatlas.org/ws/dataProvider/dp80"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to fix the `unhashable type` error and display valid JSON. If so, you can correct the error by changing `data_providers` dictionary to a list since it contains multiple nested dictionaries.

```
output_dict = {
    'data_providers': [
        {
                    'name': 'NBN Atlas',
                    'url': 'https://registry.nbnatlas.org/datasets',
                    'api_url': 'https://registry.nbnatlas.org/ws/dataResource'
        },
        {
                    'name': owner_name,
                    'url': owner_url,
                    'api_url': owner_api_url
        }
    ]
}
```

You can now use a statement similar to `print(json.dumps(output_dict))` to display the result as JSON.